# MySQL performance using where

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

A simple query like the one below, properly indexed on a table populated with roughly 2M rows is taking `95 rows in set (2.06 sec)` a lot longer to complete than I was hoping for.

As this is my first experience with tables this size, **am I looking into normal behavior**?

Query:

```
  SELECT t.id, t.symbol, t.feed, t.time, 
         FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.time)/(60*15)) as diff
    FROM data as t 
   WHERE t.symbol = 'XYZ' 
     AND DATE(t.time) = '2011-06-02' 
     AND t.feed = '1M' 
GROUP BY diff  
ORDER BY t.time ASC;
```

...and `Explain`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key    | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref  | unique,feed,symbol | symbol | 1       | const | 346392 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show your indices and table structure as well?

Comment: As far as normalcy goes, usually you can set indices that remove the need for the filesort, and often the temporary table as well. However, I'm not one of those MySQL wizards who can do that :P

Comment: try creating a key on `(symbol, time, feed)`. also try not to use `DATE()` in your where clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
AND t.time >= '2011-06-02' AND t.time < '2011-06-03' 
...
```

Otherwise, your index(es) are wrong for this query. I'd expect **one** on `(symbol, feed, time, id)` or  `(feed, symbol, time, id)` to cover it.

Edit, after comment:

If you put a function or processing on a column, any index is liable to be ignored. The index is on `x` not `f(x)` basically.

This change allows the index to be used because we now do `a <= x < y` to ignore the time part, not `takeofftime(x)`

Comment: `95 rows in set (0.05 sec)`, outstanding. Thank you! Would you care to explain a bit more on why? Going to get some rest now. Will accept tomorrow (9 more minutes still to allow accept).